# How can I store my static files to some other github repo?

Tags: django, file, github, django-rest-framework, static

I am doing a Django Project and I want to store some files (which should be accessible from the project w,r) to some github project as I don't want to store the files and the projects in the same repo.

Any suggestion of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, for example, that you want to upload all files with a `.css` extension to a separate project.

You need to create two files in the root folder of each project. and call them `.gitignore`
(Don't forget the point at first)

In the repository where you want all files except `css` files, write in the  `.gitignore` file:

```
*.css
```

In the repository where you only want the css files, write in the `.gitignore` file:

```
*
!*.css
```

You will now push the `.gitignore` files, respectively, to each of the projects you created.